# What are commonly used ontologies for spatial relations with terms like "delimit"?

Tags: geospatial, wikidata

Currently, on Wikidata there is an open proposal to have a projecty about [delimit](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Property_proposal/delimit) which is supposed to have the meaning of "Walls of Jerusalem delimit Old City of Jerusalem".

For good interoperability in Open Data it's very useful when different datasets use the same word to mean the same thing.

What other popular datasets have spatial relations relationships like "delimit" that contain prior art that might positively inform the creation of our Wikidata property?

Comment: Perhaps one of [these](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/terms?q=bound).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linked Open Vocabularies](http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/terms?q=bound) at [okfn](/questions/tagged/okfn) is a common place for searching existing linked data terms.

At 20 January 2018, the property has been created as [has boundary (`wd:P4777`)](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P4777), inspiring by http://geovocab.org/geometry#boundary (see the property proposal).

Answer (score 1):

The [OBO Relation Ontology](http://obofoundry.org/ontology/ro) is an ontology of relationship types that has many spatial relations that are axiomatized in OWL/SWRL. The focus of this ontology is the life sciences, but the same relations we use to say that a cell is [surrounded by](http://obofoundry.org/ontology/ro) a cell wall can also be used to describe e.g. city boundaries. In fact the RO is being used by a broader range of ontologies such as [Environment Ontologies](http://obofoundry.org/ontology/envo) and [the Common Core Ontologies](https://github.com/CommonCoreOntology/CommonCoreOntologies)

There is a GitHub tracker in the link and you are welcome to make requests for new spatial relations (disclaimer: it is likely me or one of my colleagues that will answer on that tracker)